# how to print get, find, create value using angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to retrieve get, find, create,update, delete values in table.

```
"classLevelPermissions" :
      {
        "find": {

            _admin : true, '*' : true
        },

          "get": {  _admin : true, '*' : true
        },
        "create": { _admin : true },
        "update": { _admin : true },
        "delete": { _admin : true },
      }
```

i want exact output like below

```
RoleName | Get | Find | Create | Update | Delete
 _admin    | yes | yes  | yes    |  no    | yes
```

print yes when value is true and no when value is false. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried sofar ?

Comment: You question is not clear on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to get values corresponding for input?

Comment: i want to print this in table form using angular 6. I am not getting how to display this json key value in component.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that,  `_admin` is a fixed key.
Here is my [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zzlss)

Comment: can you please solve my problem using remote access?